# FMDB unable to open database file(on iphone only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite, fmdb

I saw many people asked this question, however no solution helped me.

I'm using FMDB to query a localDB, I'm not using insert or something like this, I only read from the DB.

On the simulator everything work as expected and for some reason on iPhone FMDB unable to open the db.

Please note the DB is loaded in the following code, and I can see in debug that that the DB is loaded.

```
    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"book"
                                                         ofType:@"sqlite"];
    self.db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:filePath];
```

When I query the DB in the following code I get FMResultSet nil, and in the logs I can see

> DB Error: 14 "unable to open database file"
>
> DB Query: SELECT * from Book
>
> DB Path: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/91978CA9-748E-442B-9986-516830235D74/GreatBoox.app/book.sqlite

```
 BOOL isOpen = [self.db open];
if ([self.db hadError]) {
    NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [self.db lastErrorCode], [self.db lastErrorMessage]);
}
FMResultSet *f = [self.db executeQuery:@"SELECT * from Book"];
```

Please note: isOpen = YES, and the log from "hadError" dosen't print, the problem(and logs) happening in the FMResultSet line.

Can someone shed some light on the issue?

Thanks.